# Installed DocBlox with Wamp and PEAR

Tags: php, xslt, wamp, docblox

I've been trying to get [DocBlox](http://www.docblox-project.org/) working on windows.  I'm running wamp server with PHP version 5.3.9.  I've enabled XSL and its showing in phpinfo as well as if I run a test script, XSLTProcessor is available.

I installed DocBlox from PEAR.  It runs, however I get the error that the XSL writer was unable to find your XSLTprocessor.

Any ideas?  Thank you!

Comment: Did you enable the php_xsl extension?

Comment: Yeah, It's enabled.  Double checked php.ini and it shows in phpinfo

Comment: sorry, stupid question, I overread it in your description..

Answer (score 1):

The error that you are receiving means that php does not recognize the xsl extension. Php has got a separate ini file for CLI and web; and I presume that you have enabled the xsl extension for apache only.

You can verify this by executing php -i in your command prompt and check if the xsl extension is enabled there. If not then add your dll to the right config for your WAMP.

Comment: God sent. Using WAMP, had to un-comment xsl.dll in the php.ini within the PHP folder.