# DocBlox error: The XSL writer was unable to find your XSLTProcessor

Tags: docblox

I am using WAMP on my local machine and I'm trying to use docblox to generate documentation for a project.

When i try to run the docblox command in my command prompt for a file that has the necessary comments, I get the error message.

C:\wamp\www\wm-ppclps>docblox run -f wm-ppclps.php -t documentation
DocBlox version 0.18.1

Starting transformation of files (this could take a while depending upon the size of your project)
ERROR: The XSL writer was unable to find your XSLTProcessor; please check if you
 have installed the PHP XSL extension

I have no idea why this is error message is appearing. The command creates the documentation folder, parses the source code and it produces the structure.xml file. It just won't transform the structure into an HTML file or any other readable file.

I added the PHP install directory to my system path, I installed PEAR system wide, added PEAR install directory to my system path, installed DocBlox using the docblox pear channel, I have the necessary environment variables setup. I uncommented the php.ini line to enable the php_xsl.dll extension for WAMP and restarted WAMP. When I view the phpinfo, i see that the XSL extension is enabled (XSL version 1.1.23, compiled against libxml version 2.6.32, EXSLT enabled).

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, has come across this problem or can point me in the right direction for an answer?

Comment: Possible Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213783/installed-docblox-with-wamp-and-pear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that you are receiving means that php does not recognize the xsl extension.
Php has got a separate ini file for CLI and web; and I presume that you have enabled the xsl extension for apache only.

You can verify this by executing `php -i` in your command prompt and check if the xsl extension is enabled there. If not then add your dll to the right config for your WAMP.

Comment: thank you. that is ballin and helped out a lot. Never knew that about PHP's CLI.